# "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String[]' while attempting to activate 'kaneki.Configuration.ApplicationSettings'."

Tags: c#

System.InvalidOperationException: "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String[]' while attempting to activate 'kaneki.Configuration.ApplicationSettings'."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как пофиксить?

Comment: попробуйте перенести выше по коду регистрацию сервиса ApplicationSettings

Comment: не сработало, но я другую фишку сделал, и пофиксилось, но спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @mugetsuHKG, Вы поделитесь, как пофиксили-то.